# app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease task filed due to download errors from repositories inside android studio while signing APK

Tags: android, android-studio, maven, gradle

I'm stuck with the error `Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease'.` while I'm going to make signed version of my android application.

This is due to failure to download some jar files such as:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/31.0.0/lint-gradle-31.0.0.jar

Here is the complete log in my android studio:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not find lint-gradle-31.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:31.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/31.0.0/lint-gradle-31.0.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-31.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint:31.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/31.0.0/lint-31.0.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-checks-31.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:31.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/31.0.0/lint-checks-31.0.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-api-31.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:31.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/31.0.0/lint-api-31.0.0.jar
   > Could not find intellij-core-31.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:31.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/31.0.0/intellij-core-31.0.0.jar
   > Could not find kotlin-compiler-31.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:31.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/31.0.0/kotlin-compiler-31.0.0.jar
   > Could not find uast-31.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:31.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/31.0.0/uast-31.0.0.jar
   > Could not find play-sdk-proto-31.0.0.jar (com.android.tools:play-sdk-proto:31.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/play-sdk-proto/31.0.0/play-sdk-proto-31.0.0.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Some methoes suggested to [disable lint through gradle configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932222/getting-an-error-execution-failed-for-task-applintvitalrelease) which is a work-around not a real remedy for the real error. And [some other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972122/could-not-find-com-android-tools-lintlint-gradle-android-studio-3) suggessted to reorganize the order of repositories inside `build.gradle` or etc.

So at the end, of question I put my `build.gradle` file and I would be thankful if you can suggest how to resolve that?

I should notice some important notes:

1. Files are accessible in my computer by their URL. I mean when I copy the missing file link if browser it will start downloading.
2. I've tried diffrenet network connection but situation did not changed.

I want to know are there any methods to download these file somewere inside my computer so android studio can use them without need to download them? I saw that android studio stored the jar files like this in some sort of hashed folder inside its cache like this:

`C:\UserHome\gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.lint\lint-api\26.4.2\f7138e14eb007b469f368f69b06aed1d51b8afcc\lint-api-26.4.2.jar`

or
`C:\UserHome\gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.external.com-intellij\intellij-core\26.4.2\e848324c1801623cf2bbeb5e6841413d30d87ced\intellij-core-26.4.2.jar`

But I cannot guess how to find the right hash/checksum for files missed to put them in android studio cache.

So if you know any method to resolve my issue or any method to download file and put them in right place I would be thankful if you share that.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    //ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'/*'1.3.31'*/


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter() // required for performance sdk
        maven {
            url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.lint/lint-gradle-api'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0')
        //classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
        //classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2'

        // Add the dependency for the Performance Monitoring plugin
        //classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'  // Performance Monitoring plugin


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```